# Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'signInSilently'

Tags: ios, iphone, google-calendar-api, swift5, gidsignin

What is this error, please guide no material found anywhere on google so far. Below is my code which is giving error:

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() == false {
               GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
           } else {
               if let user = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser {
                   service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
                   fetchEvents()
               } else {
                   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
               }
           }
```

Two errors coming:

```
Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'hasAuthInKeychain'
Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'signInSilently'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the `GIDSignIn` version you are using. 
From `v5.0.0`:

`signInSilently` has been replaced with `restorePreviousSignIn`.

`hasAuthInKeychain` has been replaced with `hasPreviousSignIn`.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release